# Declaring css imports

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately I didn't know how to name my question correctly.

I saw 2 different implementations on how to import a css file in a html file.

Solution 1:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../styles.css" />
```

Solution 2:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import  "../styles.css";
```

I would like to know what the difference is and if one solution should be preferred over the other.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the first one

Comment: @TimGerhard Thank you for your comment. And should I include the "profile" line, as is that not necessary for most browsers anymore?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../styles.css" /> is enough

Comment: The "profile" link has nothing to do with stylesheets, so it is irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think the linked question mentions this, but the @import rule was only created to cater to situations where you can't change the HTML to add a new <link>, but you can change the CSS. Say in very restricted CMS's and such.